# React Native authorization with Apollo: create client with token. Cannot set token to header

Tags: react-native, authentication, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

```
let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
let client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'https://39990dea.ngrok.io/graphql',
});

let init = async () => {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!!token) {
        store.dispatch(userLoaded(token));
        client = new ApolloClient({
            request: (operation) => {
                operation.setContext({
                    headers: {
                        authorization: token ? token : '',
                    },
                });
            },
        });
        console.warn('user with token created');
        console.warn(token);
        console.warn('token is taken');
    }
    setLoading(false);
};
useEffect(init, []);
```

There i am creating apollo client. Then I set header to request with token if there is a token in AsyncStorage.

```
return (
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigator/>
    </Provider>
</ApolloProvider>
```

);

But when i make request, Graphql error: notoken shows up. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing your client and asynchronously changing it but your component is not re-rendering. So you have two options:

> useState so that your app re-rendered

or

> call `forceUpdate` function